# Ipad Air totally unresponsive

Tags: ipad

I was just using it and I let the screen go off and now it will  not do anything. I tried plugging it into a computer. It won't turn on or off. The battery was not low.

Comment: Try holding `Home` + `Power` button for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you still follow the traditional steps which does let you charge it for at least 30 minutes just to be sure the battery indication wasn't stuck at an incorrect reading:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3274

If none of the steps there work, you'll need to take it in for hardware service or a replacement.

Comment: I tried plugging it into a computer but it doesn't even come up with the little thing either. Plus I had it on the charger ALL last night. It's been unplugged for 2 hours.